# i'm writng regist html ,django + ajax,partial load page,but memory is increased and the page is stuck

Tags: javascript, django

django veiews

```
def regist(request):
    hashkey = CaptchaStore.generate_key()
    image_url = captcha_image_url(hashkey)
    captcha = {'image_url': image_url, 'hashkey':hashkey}
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        key = request.POST['hashkey']
        capt = request.POST['captcha']
        if username != '' and password != '' and password1 != '':
            if len(password) >= 6:
                if captchautil.is_valid(capt, key):
                    check_user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
                    if not check_user:
                        if password == password1:
                            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
                            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, name=username, level='Bronze')
                            msg = '注册成功，现在去登录吧'
                        else:
                            msg = '密码不一致,请重新输入'
                    else:
                        msg = '用户名已存在,请重新输入'
                else:
                    msg = '请输入正确的验证码'
            else:
                msg = '密码长度至少6位'
        else:
            msg = '请输入用户名与密码'
        return HttpResponse(msg)
    return render(request, 'regist.html', locals())
```

html code

```
<form action="/regist/" method="post" id="myForm">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id='username' name="username">
<input type="password" id='password' name="password">
<input type="password" id='password1' name="password1">
<input  id='captcha' name="captcha" required>
<input value="{{hashkey}}" type="hidden" name="hashkey" id='hashkey'>
<button type="submit" name="click" id='click'>注册</button>
```

script code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'regist' %}",
                data: {
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password,
                    "password1": password1,
                    "key": hashkey,
                    "capt": captcha,
                    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(response){
                    alert(response);
                    $("#myForm").submit();                
                },
            });
```

My intention is to load the returned results directly into 'div', without loading all html.
But when I submit it, the whole page gets stuck directly, and the browser memory goes up. Only when I close the page can I get back to normal.
and i'm try ajax return false,but it will happen again
html code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'regist' %}",
                data: {
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password,
                    "password1": password1,
                    "key": hashkey,
                    "capt": captcha,
                    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(response){
                    alert(response);
                    $("#myForm").submit();                
                },
            });
return false;
```

I think the reason for this is that Ajax didn't submit the data. I didn't see the message in the server request log, and it has been creating new variables, causing the browser memory to increase and the page to get stuck. But I haven't found the line where it happened.
Hope your answer can solve the problem.thk

Comment: I wrote a test separately, and found that it was the problem of the verification code. If you don't have the verification code, you can submit it normally and load it locally, but if you have the verification code, you will get an error.

Comment: Yes, now it can be really the problem of verification code. When I remove the verification code, it works normally. But when I add it, the log of the server will report an error and record 'Django. Utils. Datastructures. Multivaluedictkeyerror:' hashkey '. So I think the way for the front end to get the' hashkey 'value is wrong, but I haven't found a way to get the' hashkey 'value yet.